# .bib file from different location is not working

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have my master `.bib` file `Masterbib.bib` in a separate directory and my `.tex` file in different folder. I am using TeXstudio. Though it is executing without errors but fails to recognize the `.bib` file from another folder.

```
Location of .tex file: C:\Users\MMatam\Desktop\MainDrive\Papers_subtd_Acceptd\Project1\Draft_folder\body.tex

Location of .bib file: C:\Users\MMatam\Desktop\MainDrive\ReferencePapers/Masterbib.bib
```

My bib declartion in the .tex file:

```
\bibliography{C:\Users\MMatam\Desktop\MainDrive\ReferencePapers\Masterbib.bib}{}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

For unknown reasons, it is not working.

[image]

Comment: Note that the file name in `\bibliography` *must* be given without the file extension (`.bib`), so `\bibliography{C:\Users\MMatam\Desktop\MainDrive\ReferencePapers\Masterbib}` would be correct. I think TeX live is more tolerant here and doesn't complain if you include the `.bib`, but my MikTeX system doesn't like that at all. Do things work if you remove the incorrect extension? Do you get any error in the `.blg` file?

Comment: @moewe THanks for the nice response. I am getting lost. I recently uninstalled the TEXstudio I had and installed the version shown on the website. I frequently encouter this problem of \endbiblography not found. Though the .tex and .bib files both in same folder. I have updated my question. Any help?

Comment: Again the screenshot shows that you are including the `.bib` file extension in the call to `\bibliography`. The correct call would be `\bibliography{MMbib}` and **not** `\bibliography{MMbib.bib}{}` (the second pair of braces is also superfluous, but shouldn't cause much trouble). (Please note that it is much better to include code as copy-and-paste-able text and not as images: Images can be hard to read and pose an accessibility issue for people with screen readers: Plus it is a pain having to re-type the code if we want to try it...)

Comment: If you copy the .bib file to the same folder as the .tex (and remove the path in `\bibliography`) does it compile? successfully?  Assuming you use biber, what does that say when you run it?

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks for the response. Now both files are in same folder. Previously working fine. Now Surprisingly it started giving error as I shown in my above screenshot.

Comment: @moewe Yes! I removed the `{}` yet it the problem persists.

Comment: In that case you need to very carefully address what's different from before in both the .tex and the .bib files.  Something has changed, and the location of the .bib file may be a distraction from the real issue

Comment: The `{}` wasn't the main point of my comment (I probably shouldn't have brought it up as it most definitely wasn't the cause of the issue, sorry): The important bit was removing the `.bib` from the `\bibliography` call. It should be `\bibliography{MMbib}` *without* the `.bib` extension.

Comment: @ChrisH I have both files stored in same folder. I deleted all the auxiliary files and then executed. It is giving same error as in my above screenshot. I am surprised and do not know what to do. Probably I should have not uninstalled my previous TEX studio.

Comment: @moewe You are right. It works without .bib extenstion. and now it is working. Thanks a ton. This is what I have included `\bibliography{MMbib}{}`.

Comment: @ChrisH `\bibliography{MMbib}{}` solved my problem. But I could not address my main problem that is refering the bib file from totally different folder. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try `\bibliography{C:\Users\MMatam\Desktop\MainDrive\ReferencePapers\Masterbib}`? In case that doesn't work, try `\bibliography{C:/Users/MMatam/Desktop/MainDrive/ReferencePapers/Masterbib}` (backslashes have a special meaning for TeX and I don't know if `\bibliography` works around that).

Comment: @moewe You are right. backslash gave lot of errors. So I did not use it. Instead, This what I tried `\bibliography{C:/Users/MMatam/Desktop/OneDrive - University of Central Florida/00UCF_FSEC_Manju/0Paper_Submitted_Accepted/MMbib}{}` It is giving same error as in above screenshot that is \endbiblography error. I admit that there are gaps in folder names. This how it is.